# Entity or DTO approach for SpringJDBC template?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I have a Java Batch job which uses plain JDBC to execute lot of queries with lot of joins.  I decided to convert the plain JDBC code  to  **Spring JDBC** project which uses **JDBCTemplate**.
Its purely a command line batch program and there is no GUI.  There are around 40 tables and  4-5 tables have 300+ columns. I am not sure whether to create Entity classes for those tables  or  create DTO pojo classes?

I understand that DTO classes are to decouple the entity classes and view.  Since I do not have GUI and I am dealing with only DB with lot of handmade queries with joins , is it better to use only entity classes  instead of DTO classes  ?   I'm not using JPA , instead I am using spring JDBC.

So the code looks like

```
 List<Customer> customers = jdbcTemplate.query(
                sql,
                new BeanPropertyRowMapper(Customer.class));
```

Here the Customer  should be  a Entity class or DTO?  Please advise.

Comment: Entities are a good way to represent your database structure if you want to work on an object model instead on a database but if you don't need to work on an object model entities are of not much use

Comment: One class for query result structure is needed. It does not matter if you call it "entity" or "dto". I suppose the queries do not return the same structure even for same tables, therefore approach closer to "traditional dto" approach is needed. Btw if the SQLs are read-only (selects) then even with JPA/Hibernate one might query directly into "dto".

Comment: Any sample code available to how to work with DTO in spring boot JDBC template and REST API

Answer (score 2):

The traditional approach is:

1. Use `CustomerEntity` on the `@Repository` level.
2. Use `CustomerDto` on the `@Service` level.

In your case I would prefer to use:

1. `CustomerEntity` — if it corresponds to a `CUSTOMERS` table row. `CustomerEntity` can have relations, for example `List<OrderEntity>`.
2. For aggregate data (select query with multiple joins) `CustomerReportDto` can be used (or just `CustomerReport`).
3. `CustomerResponse` for an endpoint response.

Comment: CustomerReport as like  View object classes?   Suppose if I have a select query with multiple joins from different tables ,  then  in that case I can have a view object class or a dto?

Comment: @Stunner Yes. It is something like View. So you can use `CustomerReport`. You can consider it as DTO without DTO postfix.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Both.

Use Entity for db operation like insert,update etc...

Use DTO for passing data from REST API to Service or Service to REST API.
For this you need to use converter for DTO to ENTITY and ENTITY to DTO at service level.
Sometime it happens that from front or REST API, we will be getting some extra information which may need for some calculation but not for DB so in that case it is good to use DTO and ENTITY.

Comment: He does not have REST API.

Comment: Still he can use.It is not necessary to have GUI or REST.Some way he is hitting service so in that case he can use.

Comment: Of course he can use them if it makes sense. It makes less sense however to write an answer relating to REST API when he writes he has command line batch job.

Comment: @Sanjay .. Its a standalone commandline batch job which will hit DB and generate reports. It doesn't expose any service or API.   Could you please be specific why should I have to use  DTO in my case..